# What is the android layout designer seen in udacity?

Tags: android, layout, designer

I recently came across an Android design course in Udacity, and I noticed they are using an interactive layout designer in the video.
**Does anyone know what is the name of this designer?**

I am hoping it's not a custom tool made only for Google engineers. The layout designers in Eclipse and Android studio are definitely not as easy as this one.

You can see it in the Udacity video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O47H4PxMf9U&feature=youtu.be&t=30s

Comment: I don't see an interactive layout designer at that point in the video. I see a resizeable preview. Is that what you mean? You may wish to annotate a screen capture of what you are seeing, upload that somewhere, and link to it from your question, so we know exactly what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this thing here: https://github.com/romannurik/LayerVisualizer/

Not exactly a Layout designer but is really good to pre visualize layouts